# Retrieving data from multiple tables with .Include()

Tags: linq, lambda, entity-framework-core

Is this is the right approach to retrieve data? This is the only way I was able to retrieve all tasks with corresponding categories for a user. If I would have the where clause before .ToList() it would give me an exception (the ApplicationUser would be null). What I dont like about this approach is that I retrieve all the data from database first, and then parse it out farther to return data only for specific user. For some case that .Include() method does not work as I would assume it would.

```
public IEnumerable<Task> GetAllTasksForUser(string username)
    {
        return _db.Tasks
                .Include(t => t.Category)
                .Include(t => t.Category.ApplicationUser)
                .ToList()
                .Where(t => t.Category.ApplicationUser.UserName == username);
    }
```

This one is erroring out:

```
try
        {
            var x = _db.Tasks
                .Include(t => t.Category)
                .Include(t => t.Category.ApplicationUser)
                .Where(t => t.Category.ApplicationUser.UserName == username)
                .ToList();

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
```

Generated working sql statement retrieved from Profiler. When I run the generated query, it retrieves data, but it throws mentioned exception with linq. This .Include() is killing me:

```
> SELECT [t].[TaskId], [t].[CategoryId], [t].[Description], [t].[Name], [t].[Timestamp], [t.Category].[CategoryId], [t.Category].[Description], [t.Category].[Name], [t.Category].[Timestamp], [t.Category].[UserId], [t.Category.ApplicationUser].[Id], [t.Category.ApplicationUser].[AccessFailedCount], [t.Category.ApplicationUser].[ConcurrencyStamp], [t.Category.ApplicationUser].[Email], [t.Category.ApplicationUser].[EmailConfirmed], [t.Category.ApplicationUser].[LockoutEnabled], [t.Category.ApplicationUser].[LockoutEnd], [t.Category.ApplicationUser].[NormalizedEmail], [t.Category.ApplicationUser].[NormalizedUserName], [t.Category.ApplicationUser].[PasswordHash], [t.Category.ApplicationUser].[PhoneNumber], [t.Category.ApplicationUser].[PhoneNumberConfirmed], [t.Category.ApplicationUser].[SecurityStamp], [t.Category.ApplicationUser].[TwoFactorEnabled], [t.Category.ApplicationUser].[UserName], [c].[CategoryId], [c].[Description], [c].[Name], [c].[Timestamp], [c].[UserId], [a].[Id], [a].[AccessFailedCount], [a].[ConcurrencyStamp], [a].[Email], [a].[EmailConfirmed], [a].[LockoutEnabled], [a].[LockoutEnd], [a].[NormalizedEmail], [a].[NormalizedUserName], [a].[PasswordHash], [a].[PhoneNumber], [a].[PhoneNumberConfirmed], [a].[SecurityStamp], [a].[TwoFactorEnabled], [a].[UserName], [c0].[CategoryId], [c0].[Description], [c0].[Name], [c0].[Timestamp], [c0].[UserId]
FROM [Tasks] AS [t]
INNER JOIN [Categories] AS [t.Category] ON [t].[CategoryId] = [t.Category].[CategoryId]
LEFT JOIN [AspNetUsers] AS [t.Category.ApplicationUser] ON [t.Category].[UserId] = [t.Category.ApplicationUser].[Id]
INNER JOIN [Categories] AS [c] ON [t].[CategoryId] = [c].[CategoryId]
LEFT JOIN [AspNetUsers] AS [a] ON [c].[UserId] = [a].[Id]
INNER JOIN [Categories] AS [c0] ON [t].[CategoryId] = [c0].[CategoryId]
ORDER BY [t.Category].[UserId]
```

This one works, but results do not include Category and ApplicationUser:

```
return _db.Tasks
.Where(t => t.Category.ApplicationUser.UserName == username)
.ToList();
```

And my models:

```
 public class Task
{
    [Key]
    public int TaskId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}

    public class Category
{
    [Key]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }

    public string UserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

Error Stack Trace:

> at lambda_method(Closure , InternalEntityEntry )
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.SimpleNonNullableDependentKeyValueFactory`1.TryCreateFromCurrentValues(InternalEntityEntry entry, TKey& key)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.WeakReferenceIdentityMap`1.CreateIncludeKeyComparer(INavigation navigation, InternalEntityEntry entry)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryBuffer.IncludeCore(Object entity, INavigation navigation)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryBuffer.Include(QueryContext queryContext, Object entity, IReadOnlyList`1 navigationPath, IReadOnlyList`1 relatedEntitiesLoaders, Int32 currentNavigationIndex, Boolean queryStateManager)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryBuffer.Include(QueryContext queryContext, Object entity, IReadOnlyList`1 navigationPath, IReadOnlyList`1 relatedEntitiesLoaders, Boolean queryStateManager)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.GroupJoinInclude.Include(Object entity)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.GroupJoinInclude.Include(Object entity)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryMethodProvider.<_GroupJoin>d__26`4.MoveNext()
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.<SelectManyIterator>d__163`3.MoveNext()
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.<_TrackEntities>d__15`2.MoveNext()
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.LinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext()
>      at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>      at .GetAllTasksForUser(String username) in :line 31

Comment: *If I would have the where clause before .ToList() it would give me an exception (the ApplicationUser would be null)* No, it wouldn't "give you an exception". Before materializing the query, everything you write is just metadata for generating the SQL query. This `Where` should be before `ToList`. `Include` has no relation to the query, but controls what will be populated in your objects, again only when the query is materialized.

Comment: `Category` and `ApplicationUser` are  `Lists` or single objects ?

Comment: It gives me exception, just like I have mentioned, it says that "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." (it is for ApplicationUser). I think you are incorrect, that .Include() is causing it.

Comment: Assuming you get an exception, could you post the exception stack trace then?

Comment: sure, just updated my question

Comment: Why didn't you say it's EF Core from the beginning! It's still quite unstable and buggy, don't waste your time with it. Wait for v.1.1 or later.

Answer (score 0):

Did you missed foreign key to ApplicationUser in Category entity? You have just navigational property define to ApplicationUser. Try setting this relationship; IMO, the query which errors out will work fine once this relation is set.

Comment: Good point, however it did not resolve my issue. I have updated my models and regenerated my tables, while now I have the user foreign key in my Category, still same issue.

Comment: @lucas but still I don't see that foreign key in your entity.

Comment: I will update my question... done. The database data was properly populated, I have the corresponding userId for categories in the table

Comment: Any specific reason for your application user primary key to be 'string'? If you don't mind, could you try withinteger and  DbGenerated options Identity? Not sure whether string make sense for primary key.

Comment: It is MVC app, and string is being used by Microsoft for user id primary id. GUID is the safest, not necessary the fastest though. And that is not an issue in here, since everything was populated just fine in the db

Comment: Ooh yeah..gotcha. just wondering what might have caused *at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.WeakReferenceIdentityMap1* issue

Comment: @lucas - is it possible to get the query generated by EF?

Comment: @lucas - + could you please try querying the category by filtering it with app user username and then take the tasks collection of category? Would that be more optimised?

Comment: So this works:                 var res = (from c in _db.Categories
                           where c.ApplicationUser.UserName == username
                           select c.Tasks).ToList(); But it returns a collection of task collections broken by category; I would like to return all tasks in a sinlge collection

Comment: Updated question, the generated sql retrieves data just fine, but still fails with linq, I have attached my generated sql

Comment: @lucas - try executing after commenting out Tasks collection from Category; my hunch is that should work. Please update if that works, will try explaining/ investigating tomorrow morning (IST).

Comment: This will work, but it will return Categories with Tasks instead of Tasks with corresponding Categories

Comment: Here is another interesting thing related to it. This works fine: _db.Tasks.Include(t => t.Category).ThenInclude(c => c.ApplicationUser)
                    .ToList(); But this throws error: _db.Tasks.Include(t=>t.Category).ThenInclude(c=>c.ApplicationUser)
                    .Where(t => t.Category.ApplicationUser.UserName == username)
                    .ToList();

Comment: For some very strange reason that .Include() does not work well with Where clause. There must be a reason, nevertheless, this just makes sens to be working